# mysql constraints versus keys -- and naming them

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `phppos_customers` (
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `taxable` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `cc_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc_preview` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_issuer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `tier_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `account_number` (`account_number`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `cc_token` (`cc_token`),
  KEY `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` (`tier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_people` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tier_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_price_tiers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

When creating a constraint it seems to NOT automatically create an index so I created one. Is this true? (I guess I don't know if I need both)

Does it cause any harm to name keys the same as constraints?

My understanding is:

An index is used to speed up searching

A constraint is used to ensure data integrity (For example making sure all customers point to a person)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` constraint *does* implicitly define an index on the column. So by creating the `KEY (person_id)` and `KEY (tier_id)`, you are in fact creating two separate indexes on those columns, which is redundant.

You can remove the two separately defined `KEY`s and just stick with the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints; the constraints will enforce referential integrity by indexing those columns.

If you execute `DESCRIBE phppos_customers;` and inspect the output, you should see the indicator `MUL` in the `Key` field for the table columns on which you've defined `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, as they are indeed indexed.